# How to use constructors in java, android?

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

I have a short question about the following code from

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

Here are used two Constructors, one with the id, and the other without - I don't understand why. What's the benefit?

I already read this thread:

[Why does this class have two constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859544/why-this-class-has-two-constructors)

The answer I could understand is, that I can create a Tag with id and not, but I'm trying to understand, how to know which constructor it shall use?  Is it just by the number of parameters?

```
    public class Tag {

    int id;
    String tag_name;

    // constructors
    public Tag() {

    }

    public Tag(String tag_name) {
        this.tag_name = tag_name;
    }

    public Tag(int id, String tag_name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.tag_name = tag_name;
    }

    // ...     
}
```

Comment: `Tag tag = new Tag();`, parameterless constructor; `Tag tag = new Tag("name");` constructor with string parameter;  Pretty easy for the programmer and the compiler to see the difference

Comment: Yes, only by the amount and type of the parameters passed.

Comment: Yes the order and type of the arguments make up the signature of the constructor so like Kevin said, new Tag() is the one without any parameters. new Tag("string") will be the one that takes a tag.  new Tag(123, "string") will call the constructor id number and string.. but new Tag("string", 123) will give you a compile error since there are no constructors that look like public Tag(String tag_name, int id).

Comment: All answers are already provided. However, the default constructor (the one that does not accept any parameters) is not really necessary to be implemented, as it will be defined by the compiler when left out of the implementation. Trying to decide which one to use is just by looking at the signature (thus params) provided.

Comment: @RvdV79 Not true. The compiler only synthesizes a default parameter when the user does not define one themselves.

Comment: @TomG, I thought I wrote that (in fact it was what I meant writing it with 'when left out of the implementation')... Forgive me for being unclear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, only by its amount of parameters.

It's called "overloading" of functions. You can overload a function by providing the same signature with different parameters (according to their type and order).

The JVM will then decide which method to use in a certain situation.

Please note:
If you provide a constructor the JVM won't provide a default constructor any more.

```
class Foo{

private int x;
private String name;

    Foo(int x){      //constructor 1
        this(x, "Default Name");
    }
    Foo(String name){  //constructor 2
        this(0, name);
    }
    Foo(int x, String name){  //constructor 3
        this.x = x;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

Foo f1 = new Foo(9); //calls constructor 1, who will call constructor 3
                     //f1.x = 9, f1.name = "Default Name"
Foo f2 = new Foo("Test"); // calls constructor 2, who will call constructor 3
                          // f2.x = 0; f2.name = "Test"
Foo f3 = new Foo(3, "John"); //calls constructor 3
                             // f3.x = 3; f3.name = "John"

Foo f4 = new Foo()  // This won't work! No default Constructor provided!
```

Answer (score 0):

**which constructor it shall use? only of its amount of paremeters?
**
Yes, for example If you call

```
Tag newTag = new Tag();
```

it will call

```
 public Tag() {

}
```

but if you call

```
 Tag newTag = new Tag("Name");
```

it will call

```
 public Tag(String tag_name) {

}
```

and so on

by how many arguments you pass to the constructor that way it will know which one to call

Answer (score 0):

The compiler knows "which constructor it shall use" by a rule, in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9).

A resume:
Is by signature of the method (the type and order of arguments --- the exceptions dont effect the signature, and the return type too). This is not restricted only by the constructor, but any method, properly Overloaded; You can study these by topic of "Overloading". The reason to Overload a method --- or a constructor too ---, is to give more flexibility.